# How does Modular Multiplicative Inverse Resolve Overflows for Large Factorials?

Tags: java, algorithm, math

I was referring to the question "Sorted Permutation Rank with Repeats" on InterviewBit and my solution could produce the correct outputs except for long string values. This is typically caused by overflows for large factorials.

I've produced a work-around by using the BigInteger math class from Java, but the solution hints advised using the "Modular Multiplicative Inverse" as a workaround alternative instead for calculating (N-1)! / (p1! * p2! * p3! ... ) where p1, p2 and p3 are the frequency of duplicate characters in the string.

So my question is, how does the "Modular Multiplicative Inverse" help resolve large factorial values that do not fit into the integer primitive type, and what is the mathematical intuition behind it? I do know how to solve this programming question, but the only part that prevents a successful submission are long string values.

Greatly appreciate any explanation on this! My solution is produced below, without using the BigInteger class.

```
public class Solution {

  public long fact(int n) {
        return (n <= 1) ? 1 : (n * fact(n-1));
  }

  public HashMap<Character, Integer> generateFreq(ArrayList<Character> charList){
        HashMap<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<Character, Integer>();
        for (int i = 0; i < charList.size(); i++){
          char c = charList.get(i);     
          if (!map.containsKey(c)) map.put(c, 1);
          else map.put(c, map.get(c)+1); 
        }
        return map;
    }

  public int findRank(String a) {
    char[] charArray = a.toCharArray();
    ArrayList<Character> charList = new ArrayList<Character>(charArray.length);
    ArrayList<Character> sortedCharList = new ArrayList<Character>(charArray.length);
    for (char c : charArray){
         charList.add(c);
         sortedCharList.add(c);
    }

    Collections.sort(sortedCharList); 

    long rank = 1; 
    int factNum = charArray.length - 1; 
    int matchedIndex = 0;
    int index = 0; 
    while (!sortedCharList.isEmpty()){
        char currChar = sortedCharList.get(index);
        if (currChar != charList.get(matchedIndex)){
              HashMap<Character, Integer> mapFreq = generateFreq(sortedCharList);
              if (mapFreq.get(currChar) > 1){
                  mapFreq.put(currChar, mapFreq.get(currChar)-1); 
              }
              long denom = 1; 
              for (char c : mapFreq.keySet()){
                  denom *= fact(mapFreq.get(c)); 
              }
              long factVal = fact(factNum); // prob: factVal overflows 
              rank += factVal/denom;  
              while (index < sortedCharList.size()){
                  if (sortedCharList.get(index) != currChar)break; 
                  index++; 
              }
          }
      else {
              sortedCharList.remove(index);
              index = 0; 
              factNum--; 
              matchedIndex++; 
      }
    }
    return (int) rank %1000003;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A key property you are missing here is that,

```
( A * B ) % MOD = ( A % MOD * B % MOD ) % MOD
```

We can find (factorial % MOD) using the above property so that they don't go above the MOD value and hence don't exceed the integer limit.

```
fact[1]=1;
for(int i=2;i<=n;i++)
    fact[i]= ( (fact[i-1] % MOD) * (i % MOD) ) % MOD;
```

So for finding, (N-1)! / (p1! * p2! * p3! ... )

```
ans = fact[N-1]
for(i = 1 ; i <= number_of_pi ; i++)
    ans = (ans % MOD * modular_inverse(fact[p[i]]) % MOD) % MOD;
// here p[1] = p1, p[2] = p2 and so on
```

Modular multiplicative inverse is given by,

```
(1/A) % MOD = A ^ (MOD - 2) % MOD
```

Again to find Modular inverse without overflows you will need to use modular exponentiation. You can read about it [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation).